Thought experiment with black holes and escaping rockets
Something about stuff ever falling in black holes always bothers me, so I made a thaught experiment that I would like to be scrutinized.
Element 1: We have a supermassive non rotating black hole.
Assumption 1: A rocket can cross this horizon without noticing much itself.
My understanding is, that I can cross the event horizon of such a black hole without noticing anything strange. Is this really true? What about hawking radiation if it exists?
Element 2: I have invented a rocket powerful enough to escape any kind of black hole as long as it did not cross the horizon, no matter how close it is to the horizon
Assumption 2: Given a powerful enough engine, theoretically, a rocket can escape such a black hole without harm, no matter how close it gets to the horizon, as long as it did not cross it.
Element 3: I have 1000 such Rockets and each is randomly programmed to
a) fly into the black hole and cross the horizon
b) to chose a random distance from the horizon, up to a few nanometers away and then escape
So, my question is, how long would I have to wait until I know which rocket did fall into the black hole and which did escape.
Assumption 3: I have to wait an infinite amount of time due to the time dilation effect to know if something really crossed or narrowly escaped
If all my assumptions are correct, I'd argue that nothing ever did fall into such a black hole and even could be extracted again with a powerful enough space ship, as we have infinite time to rescue it. But this raises other questions like what if the horizon of the black hole expands beyond the point where I last saw the rocket... Something is really weird suggesting that I am missing a fundamental puzzle piece or have a wrong assumption.
I hope you get my point and can answer it even if I made a small mistake in formulating it.
For example I wonder, is the time dilatation effect to infinity really at the horizon and not instead at the singularity inside the horizon? then all would make sense to me.
UPDATE Since I was asked to do it: It differentiates from other questions I could find by specifying a new kind of easy to understand thought experiment that puts the focus on exactly what I struggle with.
Answer from comments by @safesphere paraphrased by me (most likely horrible... sorry)
The Rockets don't fall in, they increase the size of the horizon before falling in which pushes them outwards (frame dragging). Their own mass makes it such that they can't escape from it even before the horizon is close (not 100% sure why though if frame dragging still keeps them outside of the horizon), so the external observer could even observe the point of no return, when it is practically impossible for mass (not photons) to escape, as the mass needed to escape itself contributes to the black hole. This point of no return for mass depends on how much mass it is and is further out than the event horizon.

This question is similar to: How can anything ever fall into a black hole as seen from an outside observer? and Can matter really fall through an event horizon?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on those questions are not helpful for your problem.

All of your assumptions are wrong. Assumption 1: This is the common interpretation of the governing equations, unfortunately without the possibility of empirical falsification. So we cannot say whether it is really true or not. Assumption 2: This is not possible. The energy required for a rocket to escape a black hole is at least equal to the rest energy of the black hole itself. So your rocket would have the mass of the black hole. The two of you would ultimately merge. Assumption 3: There is no such thing as an infinite amount of time.

@JanG You are giving the OP a hard time on technicalities. For the purposes of understanding what he is trying to understand, all his assumptions are correct. He could replace escaping rockets with emitted photons and it would be much clearer. For example, any photon emitted away from a black hole outside the horizon would escape, so no need to invent super powerful heavy rockets. I think the OP is looking for the concept of what is happening at the horizon while his rockets may not be technically the best instrument for this. Also the duplicate link is totally wrong and is not a duplicate.

@Torge (1) If you want to understand classical black holes, don’t bring up the Hawking radiation yet. There is no evidence that it exists, but if it does, it changes things dramatically. So understand classical black holes first and only then move on to the Hawking radiation. (2) All your assumptions are conceptually correct in the context of trying to understand the physics near the horizon. However, some of them may be technically wrong, such as on the amount of fuel or realistic acceleration. If you replace rockets with photons, these objections disappear, but the concept remains the same.

@Torge (3) Your conclusion, “nothing ever did fall into such a black hole”, is correct, as observed from outside. (4) “what if the horizon of the black hole expands beyond the point where I last saw the rocket” - When the horizon moves or expands, it pushes everything nearby just like ocean waves push boats up and down while keeping them at the surface. This effect is called linear frame dragging. Nothing ever crosses in or out, as observed from outside, no matter how the horizon moves, expands, vibrates, of merges with another one. Linear frame dragging is the “puzzle” you are missing.

@Torge “I wonder, is the time dilatation effect to infinity really at the horizon and not instead at the singularity inside the horizon?” - Time dilation is infinite at both places, although defining the time dilation near the singularity requires more care. This can be simpler expresses by the fact that both the horizon and the Schwarzschild singularity (of equivalently the inner horizon in a rotating black hole) are lightlike across and spacelike along. The “lightlike” part makes the time dilation infinite (same as while moving close to the speed of light in Special Relativity).

@safesphere, thank you! I know that I am discussing very theoretical. I understood that there is a theoretical limit on how close I can fly before I can't escape and I thought this was the event horizon. But I guess some weird stuff happens before due to my own mass that moves this limit further away. And this is the real point of no return and no rescue for real mass. A second event horizon you could say where you could argue philosophically that the object did fall in at that point and I could even observe it. So I know at that moment that my rockets won't make it back. Which is not infinity

@safesphere and I further conclude that mass next to the horizon, before crossing already can increase the event horizon size in my time frame, correct? What's truly new to me and indeed a missing puzzle piece is that the expansion of the horizon pushes the stuff further out, which is really weird...Is this the similar to normal space expansion that happened during inflation (and even now as far as I understood)?

@Torge So my tough answer paid off in provoking these very interesting (+1) comments from safesphere.

@Torge “mass next to the horizon, before crossing already can increase the event horizon size in my time frame” - Correct, except in any frame, not just yours. If a mass $m$ falls to a black hole $M$ with the radius $2M$ (in natural units), the horizon extends towards the falling mass and meets it at the radius $2(M+m)$. At this point the black hole becomes larger and its mass becomes $M+m$ before $m$ crosses the horizon. Note that the mass $M$ also consists of the matter that is on the outer surface of the horizon and never crossed. So $m$ joins the original matter of the collapsed star.

@Torge If you have a hypothetical unbreakable string attached to $m$ and at some point pull it out with enough force (the equivalent of you flying away from the horizon in your rocket), then the reverse happens. The black hole decreases from $R=2(M+m)$ back to $R=2M$. While such a string and force are not physically realistic, if a falling object is a photon, it can hit some falling mirror, reflect back, and fly out. The reason the horizon can decrease is because it is not the event horizon, but the apparent horizon, which is what people typically mean when they refer to the event horizon.

@Torge Frame dragging is easy to understand. Consider a rock flying toward a stationary black hole. You also are stationary relative to the black hole. What do you see? The probe slows down and practically stops at the horizon. Now imagine you are initially stationary relative to the probe. You see a black hole flying toward the probe. The horizon pushes the probe and moves it away. What you see in both scenarios is the same physics, because the only difference is your point of view. In the former it is the time dilation; in the latter it is the linear frame dragging. Both are the same thing.

I’ll delete all my comments soon to keep the comments area clean.

No, please don't it will help others as it helped me. Would be such a waste! It's a pity that the question got rejected so quickly...
